# An elementary problem on function

Tags: functions, polynomials, contest-math, functional-equations

The problem is:

> let $p(x)$ be a polynomial with real Coefficients that is non-negative for all $x$. Prove that for some $k$, there are polynomials $f_1 (x),\cdots f_k (x)$ such that $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^k (f_i (x))^2$.

I have tried a lot but don't able to make any substantial progress so that I can state it, I will be happy if anyone help how to approach this kind of problem or with any possible solutions. Thanks.

**Edit**  : *thanks* to those who tried to help with this $i=2$ version but I don't able to convert it into solution so ask for further help or any references.

Comment: I can show you that there exists $f_1$, $f_2$ such that $p = f_1^2+f_2^2$, does it interest you?

Comment: Ok, why not? It might help but you may add it as comment or as you wish! I am surely not going to react wrongly if you add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG $p$ is monic. First, $\deg p$ is even. So we can pair off the roots in complex conjugate pairs (note that any real root has even multiplicity as $p\geq0$).

So we can write $p(x)=\prod (x-a_k)(x-\bar{a_k})=q(x)\overline{q(x)}$, where $q(x)=\prod(x-a_k)$. Then there exist real polynomials $f,g$ such that $q=f+ig$. Then $$p=(f+ig)(f-ig)=f^2+g^2.$$

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. Have any idea about the complete solution?

Comment: @Cooperation the question asks to prove that for *some* $k$, we have that $p(x)$ is the sum of the squares of $k$ polynomials. I proved that $k=2$ always works. To be explicit, stick the line "We show that the result is always true for $k=2$" at the front of my solution, and this directly answers your original question.

Comment: Or, even more blithely, to write $p$ as the sum of the squares of $k>2$ polynomials, write it as the sum of the squares of $2$ polynomials, then set the other $k-2$ to be $0$

Comment: Hey! jlammy thanks but Can you show your idea please? I am unable to figure it out how can I say the rest are $0$s?

Comment: You want polynomials $f_1,\dots,f_k$ s.t. $p=f_1^2+\dots+f_k^2$. I showed that you can always write $p=f^2+g^2$. So if you really insist on having exactly $k\neq2$ polynomials (which btw isn't implied by the question), just write $p^2=f^2+g^2+0+0+0+\dots+0$

Comment: But how to prove that it summed upto $0$ for $i≥3$

Comment: I am using the deep fact that $0+0+\dots+0=0$. You do realise that the function that is constantly $0$ is a valid polynomial right?

Answer (score 1):

You know that $p \in \mathbb{R}[X]$, so by factorizing it with irreducible polynomials you can always write it as :

$$p = \lambda \prod_{i=1}^r(X-x_i)^{\alpha_i}\prod_{j=1}^s(X^2+b_jX+c_j)^{\beta_j}$$

With all $x_i$ that are real and distinct, and $\forall j \in  \{1,\dots,q \}, (b_j,c_j)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ verifying $b_j^2-4c_j<0$.

If one of the $\alpha_i$ was an odd number so you could check that $p$ would change of sign near $x_i$, it implies that all $\alpha_i$ are even numbers (because you know $p$ has always the same sign). You can now check that $\lambda \geq 0$.

Now let's factorize $\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^s(X^2+b_jX+c_j)^{\beta_j}$ in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ :
$$\prod_{j=1}^s(X^2+b_jX+c_j)^{\beta_j} = \prod_{j=1}^s(X-z_j)^{\beta_j}\prod_{j=1}^s(X-\overline{z_j})^{\beta_j}$$

But you can write $\displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^s(X-z_j)^{\beta_j} = g_1+ig_2$ where $g_1,g_2\in \mathbb{R}[X]^2$, therefore:

$$\prod_{j=1}^s(X-\overline{z_j})^{\beta_j} = \overline{\prod_{j=1}^s(X-z_j)^{\beta_j} } = \overline{g_1+ig_2}=g_1-ig_2$$

Thus:
$$\displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^s(X^2+b_jX+c_j)^{\beta_j} = \prod_{j=1}^s(X-z_j)^{\beta_j}\prod_{j=1}^s(X-\overline{z_j})^{\beta_j} = (g_1+i g_2)(g_1-ig_2) = g_1^2+g_2^2$$

Finally by taking $f_1 = \sqrt{\lambda} \left(\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^r (X-x_i)^{\alpha_i/2}\right)g_1$ and $f_2 =\sqrt{\lambda} \left(\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^r (X-x_i)^{\alpha_i/2}\right)g_2$, you have:

$$\boxed{f_1,f_2 \in \mathbb{R}[X] \text{ such that } p = f_1^2+f_2^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the contribution.Have any idea about the complete solution?

Comment: @Cooperation You're welcome. The complete solution of what?

Answer (score 0):

Since $P$ is positive, all its real roots have an even multiplicity.

So we can write $P = \prod (X-\gamma_i)(X-\overline{\gamma_i}) \prod (X-x_k)^2$, where the $\gamma_i$ are the complex roots, and the $x_k$ the real (eventually equal).

Then if we call $A = \prod (X-\gamma_i)$, we have $\overline{A} = \prod (X-\overline{\gamma_i})$. So that if we note $C = \prod (X-x_k)$, we have $$ P = AB\cdot \overline{A}B$$

Since $B$ is a real polynomial, $B=\overline{B}$.

So $P=AB\cdot\overline{AB}$.

If we note $AB = R+iQ$ with $R$ and $Q$ real polynomials, we have : $$P=R^2 + Q^2$$

So for the exercise, we can notice that $k=1$ or $2$.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution.Have any idea about the complete solution?

Comment: I don't understand. Does the "for some $k$" in your question means "there exists" or "for all"?

Comment: You probably proved a general case where $k=2$. What about other$K_{(s)}$

Comment: But if you really want $k$ polynomials, just add $k-2$ polynomials $0$. Then, if I note $f_1$ and $f_2$ my polynomials, and $f_i=0$ for $3\leqslant i\leqslant k$, you have $p=f_1^2 + f_2^2 + f_3^2 + \cdot\cdot\cdot + f_k^2$